# Query external file to show or hide a div

Tags: jquery, html, asp-classic

Been searching for how to go about this issue, but have yet to find the answer.  I'm new to JQuery and ASP which is where I'm thinking I'll need to be to accomplish this. Here's what I'm trying to do...

I have a webpage (call it "Page1") with form fields on it which some fields are auto populated from info in the URL (e.g. www.somedomain.com/Page1.html?s=value).  I also have a separate file (named "List") that has a list of values in it.

On load Page1 form field "s" is auto populated from the URL value and I would like for "Page1" to then query "List" to find the value of field "s".  If value is on the List, then show hidden form field "z".  If value is not on the List, then keep form field "z" hidden.

Any ideas how I can go about this?

Thanks,
Keith

Comment: Search "Learn Ajax" on Google.

Answer (score 0):

Use an Ajax call to fetch the external document. Check the returned data for the 'z' value and use an `if` statement to show the 'z' field if that value was found.

```
$.ajax({
  url: "list.html",
  success: function(data) {
    var zValue = $(data).find('#myValue');
    if (zValue){
      $('#myZField').show();
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Apologies if an answer without jQuery was not what you're looking for, but you could accomplish all this on the server, as you're rendering the page. Here's some pseudo code that should be fairly easy to implement in vbscript on the server:

```
<%
Dim s : s = Trim(Request("s")) & ""
Dim showHidden : showHidden = True
Dim z
If s <> "" Then 
 If ValueIsOnTheList(s, z) Then showHidden = False
End If
%>
<html>
...
<body>
...
<%If showHidden = False%>
 <visibleTag><%= z%></visibleTag>
<%Else%>
 <hiddenTag><%= z%></hiddenTag> <!-- or don't display at all -->
<%End If%>
...
```